# How to restart the node-red inside kubectl pods?

Tags: kubectl, node-red

I have deployed the node-red server as kubectl pod and it is up and running. I have modified the red.min.js, now I need to restart the node-red to reflect the changes. But I could not restart node-red, how to restart the node-red inside a kubectl pods?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, you don't.

Since the Container entrypoint is the Node-RED process you can't restart it without the pod dying at which point Kubernetes will start a new one (without your modifications)

But since `red.min.js` part of the editor, any changes to that should not need Node-RED to be restarted, you just need to force the browser to reload it (without using it's locally cached version)

Comment: @hardilib Thanks for your answer.. Yes it is working for red.min.js but I have updated the settings.js file. I have added the following line in it `process.env["NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED"] = 0;` and trying to restart it, but the line is getting deleted. Could you please give me some suggestion.?

Comment: You'll need to move that to the env section of the YAML used to define the pod,  mount a persistent volume on `/data` or create a new container with the changes baked in.